# SyntaxError print(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, python-2.x, args, keyword-argument, rouge

I've got an error as a traceback below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup_rouge.py", line 7, in <module>
    from files2rouge import settings
  File "/home/cerdas/files2rouge/files2rouge/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from files2rouge.files2rouge import main
  File "/home/cerdas/files2rouge/files2rouge/files2rouge.py", line 17, in <module>
    from files2rouge import utils
  File "/home/cerdas/files2rouge/files2rouge/utils.py", line 14
    print(*args, **kwargs)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The error occured when I'm trying to run this code:

```
def tee(saveto, *args, **kwargs):
    """Mimic the tee command, write on both stdout and file
    """
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    if saveto is not None:
        print(file=saveto, *args, **kwargs)
```

I've read and searched for similar problems, but I still can't solve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `print(args, kwargs)` instead of `print(*args, **kwargs)`